# .htaccess issue with /home/ in my URL from my controller

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'v an problem when i'm working with PHP-mvc.net.

So every time i want to go to an specific URL, i need to put /home/ in it (becouse that's the controller name)

But, i want to remove the controller name. So i think .htaccess will be the best way to solve it?

So this is how every thing looks like:

[image: The controller]

So that is the specific "home" i want to remove in the url. (if there is any other object, i also want them disappear).

Here is my .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes

RewriteBase /

# General rewrite rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You want to omit the controller name from the URL? But then how would it know what method of what class to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rename the controller and visit it via http://example.com/yournewcontrollername/methodname ?

Comment: I want an url like http://example.com/pagename Not an URL with the controller name in it.

Comment: It's an MVC. Remember that. You can try something with the RewriteRule in your .htaccess. Give me a moment and I will post an example. `RewriteRule ^controllername/methodname/?$ /examplepage [END]` Try something like this, I don't know or it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you have the `/home/method` URL calling the `method` in the `home` controller, and you want to have the `/` URL doing the same?

If so you should do it in your routing function, I guess you `explode("/", $_GET['url']);` and the 1st element is your controller name?
Check PHP [class_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) function, it should help you, if the class doesn't exists, set it to Home.

Comment: No, i want to get rid of the home in the url.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, i still use the /home function, but now i'll use it on a differend way.